# webgl motion detection: flickering output

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, motion-detection

Attempting to do simple frame subtraction with WebGL/Three.js

Current Demo: http://zebradog.github.io/camera/motion.html

Shader here: https://github.com/zebradog/camera/blob/master/js/shaders/motion.js

Output appears to be flickering/rendering every other frame. I assume it's an issue with the swapping of framebuffers in `animate()` but cannot seem to find the problem:

https://github.com/zebradog/camera/blob/master/motion.html#L139

```
if ( video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA ){
    prevTexture.image.data = videoTexture.image.data;
    videoContext.drawImage(video, 0, 0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    videoTexture.image.data = new Uint8Array(videoContext.getImageData(0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT).data);
    if(prevTexture.image.data.length) {
      prevTexture.needsUpdate = true;
    }
    videoTexture.needsUpdate = true;
  }
```